# CoreText and right alignment

Tags: ios, core-text

I'm writing a class to generate PDFs, I'll publish as I will finish it!

I'm unable to align text to the right, with the CTParagraphStyle, the text is always on the left. How does it is possible? What I'm getting wrong?

```
- (void)addText:(NSString *)text color:(UIColor *)color fontSize:(CGFloat)size floating:(BOOL)floating {
CGContextSaveGState(pdfContext);

// Prepare font
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Verdana"), size, NULL);

// Font color
CGColorRef fontColor = [color CGColor];

// Paragraph
CTTextAlignment alignment = kCTRightTextAlignment;

CTParagraphStyleSetting settings[] = {
    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(alignment), &alignment}
};

CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(settings, sizeof(settings) / sizeof(settings[0]));

// Create an attributed string
CFStringRef keys[] = { kCTFontAttributeName , kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, kCTForegroundColorAttributeName};
CFTypeRef values[] = { font, paragraphStyle, fontColor};
CFDictionaryRef attr = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **)&keys, (const void **)&values,
                                          sizeof(keys) / sizeof(keys[0]), &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
CFAttributedStringRef attrString = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, (CFStringRef)text, attr);

CFRelease(paragraphStyle);
CFRelease(attr);

// Draw the string
CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);

CGContextSetTextPosition(pdfContext, xPadding, [self relativeHeight:currentHeight+size]);


CTLineDraw(line, pdfContext);

// Clean up
CFRelease(line);
CFRelease(attrString);
CFRelease(font);

CGContextRestoreGState(pdfContext);

if(floating == NO) {
    currentHeight += size;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `CTLineDraw()` and its related code and use `CTFrameDraw()`.

Try this:

```
// Create the Core Text framesetter using the attributed string.
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attrString);

// Create the Core Text frame using our current view rect bounds.
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
CTFrameRef frame =  CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), [path CGPath], NULL);
CTFrameDraw(frame, pdfContext);
```